# Codeigniter ajax status code shows 200 but display error message

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, codeigniter

Just try to make it simple.

I'm trying to show data in my data table when I click a dropdown value

I'm using ajax to get the data from my controller

everything works fine except the results isn't showing in my view even the status code shows 200 ok

here's my Model

```
function tampil_renja(){
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->select
            (
                'lkp_program.progskpd_id AS prog_id, 
                CONCAT(msr_mstrurusan.uru_kode, '.', lkp_program.progskpd_kode) AS prog_kode,
                lkp_program.progskpd_prog_uraian as prog_uraian');
        $this->db->from('msr_mstrurusan');
        $this->db->join('lkp_program', 'msr_mstrurusan.uru_id = lkp_program.progskpd_ursid');
        $this->db->join('lkp_kegiatan', 'lkp_program.progskpd_id = lkp_kegiatan.kegskpd_prog_id');
        $this->db->join('mnv_keg_renja', 'lkp_kegiatan.kegskpd_id = mnv_keg_renja.tar_keg_id');
        $this->db->where('mnv_keg_renja.tar_keg_id is NOT NULL', NULL, FALSE);
        $this->db->order_by("lkp_program.progskpd_id", "asc");
        return $this->db->get();    
    }
```

here's my ajax code within the view

```
<div class="container-fluid">
                <header>
                    <h3 class="mb-2">Renja</h3>
                </header>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="table-responsive" style="margin-bottom: 1px;">
                        <?php 
                            if (count($skpd) > 0) { 
                        ?>

                              <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">OPD</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <select id="skpd" name="skpd" class="form-control input-sm">
                                        <option value="0">-- Pilih Perangkat Daerah--</option> 
                                        <?php
                                        foreach ($skpd as $pd) {
                                            echo "<option value='" . $pd->uk_kowil . "#" . $pd->uk_id . "'>" . strtoupper($pd->uk_nama) . "</option>";
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                        <?php 
                            } 
                            else { 
                        ?>
                            <input type='hidden' name='skpd' id='skpd' value='<?php 
                            ?>' />
                        <?php 
                            } 
                        ?>

                        <div id="listskpd" class="col-sm-1">
                            <i id="rldspin" style="margin-top:5px"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div id="jml_angg" class="text-right" style="padding-top: 8px;font-size: 13px;margin-right: 15px;">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table id="list_target" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th rowspan="3" class="text-center text-middle" style="width:1%;">No</th>
                                <th rowspan="3" class="text-center text-middle" style="width:4%;">Kode Rekening</th>
                                <th rowspan="3" class="text-center text-middle" style="width:27%;">Program/Kegiatan</th>
                                <th rowspan="3" class="text-center text-middle" style="width:20%;">Indikator Kinerja program (outcome)/ kegiatan (output) </th>
                                <th colspan="7" class="text-center text-middle" style="width:30%;">Target Renja [berdasarkan DPA] SKPD pada Tahun</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th rowspan="2" class="text-center text-middle" style=""> Satuan</th>
                                <th colspan="2" class="text-center text-middle" style="">Target Triwulan 1</th>
                                <th colspan="2" class="text-center text-middle" style="">Target Triwulan 2</th>
                                <th colspan="2" class="text-center text-middle" style="">Target Triwulan 3</th>
                                <th colspan="2" class="text-center text-middle" style="">Target Triwulan 4</th>
                                <th rowspan="2" class="text-center text-middle" style="">Target Anggaran</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-center text-middle" style="">Kin</th>
                                <th class="text-center text-middle" style="">Keu</th>
                                <th class="text-center text-middle" style="">Kin</th>
                                <th class="text-center text-middle" style="">Keu</th>
                                <th class="text-center text-middle" style="">Kin</th>
                                <th class="text-center text-middle" style="">Keu</th>
                                <th class="text-center text-middle" style="">Kin</th>
                                <th class="text-center text-middle" style="">Keu</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="datatarget">
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.js'?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js'?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){


        $('#skpd').change(function(){ 
                var arrval = $(this).val().split("#");
                var kowil = arrval[0];
                var idpd = arrval[1];
                if(idpd != 0){;
                    tampil_data_renja(kowil, idpd);
                } else {
                    $('#datatarget').DataTable.Destroy();
                    $('#datatarget').DataTable.Draw();
                    $('#datatarget').DataTable.Destroy();
                }
            }); 

        function tampil_data_renja(kowil, idpd){
            $.ajax({
                type  : 'ajax',
                url   : '<?php echo base_url()?>renja/tampil_renja/',
                async : false,
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(data){
                    var html = '';
                    var i;
                    alert(data.length);
                    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                        html += '<tr>'+
                                '<td>'+(i+1).toString()+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].prog_kode+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].prog_uraian+'</td>'+
                                '</tr>';
                    }
                    $('#datatarget').html(html);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('Could not load the data');
                }

            });
        }
```

and this is the controller

```
function tampil_renja(){
        echo json_encode( $this->m_data->tampil_renja()->result() );
    }
```

JSON result in the network tab of chrome dev tools

```
[{"prog_id":"1","prog_kode":"6.01.0118","prog_uraian":"Program Koordinasi, pembinaan dan penyelenggaraan pemerintahan, ketentraman dan ketertiban umum, perekonomian, kesejahteraan sosial dan pembangunan"},{"prog_id":"2","prog_kode":"6.01.0118","prog_uraian":"Program Koordinasi, pembinaan dan penyelenggaraan pemerintahan, ketentraman dan ketertiban umum, perekonomian, kesejahteraan sosial dan pembangunan"}]
```

any help and guide would be appreciated
sorry for my bad english by the way

Comment: please remove extra stuff and point out us to specific error.

Comment: if you have some notice or warning then you will get status code 200 but cannot parse response in normal way.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra, actualy this is my second app with exactly same structure, just difference in template only, the first one works fine, unfortunately not for this that im talk about, even the JSON result is different, i repeat myself, with exactly same models, view main content, controller and ajax function

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:
Changes made are:

1. commented `datatype` in the AJAX
2. parse `response` of success function as JSON.

   ```
      $.ajax({
           type  : 'get', // edit 1
           url   : '<?php echo base_url()?>renja/tampil_renja/',
           async : false,
           //dataType : 'json', //change over here
           success : function(data){
               data = JSON.parse(data);  //change over here
               var html = '';
               var i;
               alert(data.length);
               for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                   html += '<tr>'+
                           '<td>'+(i+1).toString()+'</td>'+
                           // '<td>'+data[i].prog_id+'</td>'+
                           '<td>'+data[i].prog_kode+'</td>'+
                           '<td>'+data[i].prog_uraian+'</td>'+
                           '</tr>';
               }
               $('#datatarget').html(html);
           },
           error: function(){
               alert('Could not load the data');
           }

       })
   ```

Comment: thanks for the response, well at least now it's not going to could not load the data alert, but the data still not showing

Comment: i have edited the code, can you please try the updated code?

Comment: still the same, nothing shown up on view, but overall my logic is correct isn't it?

Comment: well, no alert is shown after i choose a value, which mean it's neither success or error, hahaha

Answer (score 0):

You have to redraw the datatable after the element is updated on ajax call success :

```
        //fungsi tampil barang
        function tampil_data_renja(kowil, idpd){
            // var requrl = '<?php echo base_url()?>renja/tampil_renja/'+kowil+'/'+idpd;
            $.ajax({
                type  : 'ajax',
                // url   : '<?php echo base_url()?>renja/tampil_renja/'+kowil+'/'+idpd,
                url   : '<?php echo base_url()?>renja/tampil_renja/',
                async : false,
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(data){
                    var html = '';
                    var i;
                    // console.log(data.length);
                    alert(data.length);
                    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                        html += '<tr>'+
                                '<td>'+(i+1).toString()+'</td>'+
                                // '<td>'+data[i].prog_id+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].prog_kode+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].prog_uraian+'</td>'+
                                '</tr>';
                    }
                    $('#datatarget').html(html);
                    $('#list_target').DataTable.Draw(); // redraw the datatable
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('Could not load the data');
                }

            });
            // return alert(kowil);
        }
```

Comment: datatarget is id of TBody, table id is list_target, so which mean $('#list_target').DataTable.Draw(); ?

Comment: yes, but you've write `$('#datatarget').DataTable.Draw();` on you previous lines? is that intentional?

Comment: well that's just things that i've tried by myself without references

Comment: both of this are json encoded data
is https://pasteboard.co/ICcScW4.png
different with https://pasteboard.co/ICcSBLs.png?
the later is the one i facing problem now, the previous is no problem at all. with exactly same coding way, just different template

Comment: I dont understand it, the images not found